# Is std::move required to move using co_yield?

Tags: c++, move, c++20, c++-coroutine

Say I have a `std::vector` that is declared in a loop's body and `co_yield`ed:

```
some_generator<std::vector<int>> vector_sequence() {
    while (condition()) {
        std::vector<int> result = get_a_vector();
        result.push_back(1);
        co_yield std::move(result); // or just: co_yield result; 
    }
}
```

Quite obviously, `result` isn't going to be used again after being `co_yield`ed (or I am horribly mistaken), so it would make sense to move it. I tried `co_yield`ing a simple non-copyable type without `std::move` and it did not compile, so in generic code, one would have use `std::move`. Does the compiler not recognize this (compiler bug?) or is it intended by the language that `co_yield` always copies an lvalue, so I have to `std::move`? I know that `return`ing an lvalue that is a local variable looks like a copy but is guaranteed to be a move or an even better kind of copy elision, and this does not seem so much different from it.

I have read [C++: should I explicitly use std::move() in a return statement to force a move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680904/c-should-i-explicitly-use-stdmove-in-a-return-statement-to-force-a-move), which is related to this question, but does not answer it, and considered [co_return vs. co_yield when the right hand side is a temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172316/co-return-vs-co-yield-when-the-right-hand-side-is-a-temporary), which as far as I understand, is not related to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implicit move rule ([[class.copy.elision]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3)) applies to `return` and `co_return` statements and to `throw` expressions. It doesn't apply to `co_yield`.

The reason is that, in the contexts enumerated in [class.copy.elision]/3, the execution of the `return` or `co_return` statement or `throw` expression ensures that the implicitly movable entity's lifetime ends. For example,

```
auto foo() {
    std::string s = ...;
    if (bar()) {
        return s;
    }
    // return something else
}
```

Here, even though there is code after the `return` statement, it's guaranteed that *if* the `return` statement executes, then any code further down that can see `s` *will not execute*. This makes it safe to implicitly move `s`.

In contrast, `co_yield` only *suspends* the coroutine and does not *end* it in the manner of `co_return`. Thus, in general, after `co_yield result;` is evaluated, the coroutine might later resume and use the very same `result` variable again. This means that in general, it's not safe to implicitly transform the copy into a move; therefore, the standard does not prescribe such behaviour. If you want a move, write `std::move`.

If the language were to allow implicit move in your example, it would have to have specific rules to ensure that, although the variable *could* be used again after `co_yield`, it is in fact not. In your case, it might indeed be that the loop will immediately end and thus the `result` variable's lifetime will end before its value can be observed again, but in general you would have to specify a set of conditions under which this can be guaranteed to be the case. Then, you could propose that an implicit move occur only under those conditions.

Comment: But in the example, the vector would be deleted right after being yielded, since it is scoped in the while loop right? So you would still end up with copy and delete right after eachother.

Comment: Thank you for referring to clauses in the standard. “[I]n general you would have to specify a set of conditions under which this can be guaranteed to be the case.” I could imagine that the C++ standard committee thought of this case and handled it. Maybe there are good reasons against any such exception clause.

Comment: @David van rijn I don't know if a compiler is smart enough to catch such a rather obvious case when doing optimization (it likely is), but the standard isn't smart enough, and thus the compiler must reject in case of a no-copy type, even if in the binary, no copy takes place after optimizing it away.

Comment: But then it isn't specific to co_yield statements. For any object, if the compiler can prove that it is going to be destructed right after, we could consider if the compiler should be allowed to automatically convert it to an xvalue in its last use (or even forced in very restrictive circumstances).

Comment: @MarcGlisse, as an example, unnamed return value optimization is explicitly allowed by the standard even if it skips observable side-effects in the copy/move constructor before C++17. (Since C++17, it is mandatory and thus no longer an optimization.)